# Array loses all values after go trough its own method - Objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, arrays, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I have this piece of code below and I'm trying to add Objects(String elements) to an array, problem is that every time I'm out its adding's method, it goes to nil, it doesn't retain the objects.

I know I'm doing wrong, even that I already tried lot of combinations and variations, even with my own constructor _MyArray etc etc, same result... it works, but not further...

Could you help me please?

```
@interface ArraysModel()
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *MyArray;
@end

@implementation ArraysModel
@synthesize MyArray;

-(void)AddObjectToTheList:(NSString *)object {

    if(!MyArray) MyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [MyArray addObject:object];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.MyArray);
    NSLog(@"Object added %u",[self.MyArray count]);
}
-(NSMutableArray *)ObjectList {

    return self.MyArray;
    NSLog(@"%@",self.MyArray);
    NSLog(@"Object added %u",[self.MyArray count]);
}

@end
```

The header is like this:

```
@interface ArraysModel : NSObject

-(void)AddObjectToTheList:(NSString *)object;
```

And here is my call from my ViewController:

```
- (IBAction)AddToTheList {

    ArraysModel *MyObjectToAdd = [[ArraysModel alloc] init];
    [MyObjectToAdd AddObjectToTheList:TextArea.text];
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
```

Comment: instead use `self.MyArray`, use `MyArray`.  BTW, it is better to name the variable start with a lower case letter

Comment: Just a note: in `ObjectList`, the NSLog statements won't actually do anything because you return before they are called.

Comment: From the code logic, it looks like it should work(even though you should have used self.myArray). I am not sure if the issue is in the above lines. myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; should create an NSMutableArray with retain count 1 and addObject should add the object to this array. So if you are accessing self.myArray after this method call, it should have returned the myArray with this object. Try with the below answers and update here.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I think with arc enabled and bypassing the property  `MyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];` could be treated a method-scope variable. It would than be implicit autoreleased by the compiler.

Comment: This code looks like a non-ARC to me. Especially this line @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *MyArray; Is retain allowed anyway in ARC?

Comment: I just tried in a ARC-enabled project, and it happily accepts retain for properties.

Comment: Oops. I never checked that. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: anyway: what would be the use of declaring internal properties (Note: declared in an class extension), if you bypass it?

Comment: @ACB I wasnt sure either. I always used strong instead

Comment: It's good practice to set the backing iVar rather than call the setter when initialising a property, I believe.

Comment: @jrtc27, only in init… methods, because of the possibility of side effects during subclassing. what would be the need of setters anyway, if it wasnt good practice to use them?

Comment: `AddObjectToTheList` seems to be a kind of init method... of sorts... ish.

Comment: @jrtc27 no it does not: it is not creating and return an object. it is not calling the super's designated initializer. it is a very common instance method with a non-conform name.

Comment: What happened to all the answers posted? Did any moderator delete it or some bug in my browser?

Comment: @ACB: I deleted mine, because I am not sure, if I am right. and Volure DarkAngel deleted his.

Comment: @vikingosegundo, Oh okay. That explains it. `@user1806226`, can you post some more code showing how you are calling this method and when exactly the array is becoming empty?

Comment: @jrtc27: *The only places you shouldn’t use accessor methods to set an instance variable are in initializer methods and dealloc.* [Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide — Don’t Use Accessor Methods in Initializer Methods and dealloc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW6)

Comment: 1) I moved out all self. statements ... instead I used MyArray... it works... but it just add 1 object to the array/list. 2) Right qegal!!! NSLogs were after the return "silly of me" they are before now... (null) displayed. :-(

Comment: @jrtc27 So? What should I do? :-S

Comment: @All Actually It has an object, and list the objects, BUT JUST 1!!! No more are added after call the method.

Comment: Is it exactly the same as posted above? or something like, if(!MyArray) { MyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [MyArray addObject:object]; } is there?

Comment: You really need to show the method where you are calling AddObjectToTheList:. I think your problem is there

Comment: Here you are (it's the same above BTW)
@interface ArraysModel : NSObject

-(void)AddObjectToTheList:(NSString *)object; .m:
-(void)AddObjectToTheList:(NSString *)object {

    if(!MyArray) MyArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [MyArray addObject:object];
    NSLog(@"%@",MyArray);
    NSLog(@"Object added %u",[MyArray count]);

}

Comment: I did review it... but it's so simple... I really can't find what's going on...

Comment: @user1806226 That's not what I meant -- where do you actually call that method (I assume from another class).

Comment: Sorry @rdelmar Here is my call: - (IBAction)AddToTheList {
    
    ArraysModel *MyObjectToAdd = [[ArraysModel alloc] init];
    [MyObjectToAdd AddObjectToTheList:TextArea.text];
    [self.view endEditing:YES];

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same instance of ArraysModel when you call AddObjectToTheList and when you later reference MyArray?

Comment: BTW, ***PLEASE*** in the future write your code to conform to standard C++/Objective-C naming conventions -- initial upper case for classes, initial lower case for variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there's your problem -- you're alloc init'ing a new instance of ArraysModel, and therefore a new array with every call. You need to create a strong reference to your instance, and check for whether it exits, and only init if it doesn't.

In the .h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) ArraysModel *myObjectToAdd;
```

in the .m:

```
-(IBAction)AddToTheList {
    if (! self.myObjectToAdd) { 
        self.myObjectToAdd = [[ArraysModel alloc] init];
    } 
   [self.myObjectToAdd AddObjectToTheList:TextArea.text]; 
   [self.view endEditing:YES]
}
```

Comment: Mmm.... got it!

I changed to strong in its declaration instead of retain, but arrays doesn't have any direct assigning parameters.

Now how can I instantiate the class/object without initiating… ??? it's kinda tricky…

Comment: AWESOME!!! All my items listed and counted! I understood that I needed to include a strong reference in my ViewController in order to call the method... Sorry but if it's not too much to ask... could you explain briefly WHY you set self. in all cases and not the property directly... what self does in this especific case? THANKS!!! PS: How may I rate you or show my gratefulness!!! :-)